How to mock useMapEvents (which is provided by react-leaflet) in the unit test
I was trying to create a new unit test to mock UseMapEvents but I received an error message that stated "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'map' before initialization".
Do you have any solution on how to resolve this?
Please take a look at https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemapevents in case you need to know what UseMapEvent is.
Component
function MyComponent() {
  const map = useMapEvents({
    click: () => {
      map.locate()
    },
  })
  return null
}

function MyMapComponent() {
  return (
    <MapContainer center={[50.5, 30.5]} zoom={13}>
      <MyComponent />
    </MapContainer>
  )
}

Unit Test
import { useMapEvents } from 'react-leaflet';
import MyMapComponent from '.';


jest.mock('react-leaflet', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-leaflet'),
    useMapEvents: jest.fn().mockImplementation((f) => f()),
}));

it('renders region layer without crashing', async () => {
    useMapEvents.mockImplementation((handlers) => {
       handlers.click();
    });

    await act(async () => render(<MyMapComponent />));

});

I attempted to run the test, however the error message "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'map' before initialization" prevented me from passing it.
Please see a screenshot below.


Here is a snippet from my vitest setup file that mocks a subset of the useMapEvents handlers when using react-leaflet 4.2.1.
vi.mock("react-leaflet/hooks", async (importOriginal) => {
    const mod = await importOriginal<typeof import("react-leaflet/hooks")>();
    return {
      ...mod,
      useMapEvents: vi.fn((events) => {
        useEffect(() => {
          const handlers: {
            [key: string]: (
              e: Event | LeafletMouseEvent | LeafletKeyboardEvent,
            ) => void;
          } = {};

          Object.keys(events).forEach((event) => {
            const handler = (
              e: Event | LeafletMouseEvent | LeafletKeyboardEvent,
            ) => {
              let leafletEvent;
              if (event === "dblclick" || event === "contextmenu") {
                leafletEvent = {
                  originalEvent: e,
                  type: event,
                  target: e.target,
                  latlng: new LatLng(0, 0),
                  layerPoint: new Point(0, 0),
                  containerPoint: new Point(0, 0),
                  sourceTarget: e.target,
                  popup: null,
                  layer: null,
                  propagatedFrom: null,
                };
              } else if (event === "keydown") {
                leafletEvent = {
                  originalEvent: e,
                  type: "keydown",
                  target: e.target,
                  layer: "",
                  popup: "",
                  sourceTarget: e.target,
                  propagatedFrom: "",
                };
              } else if (event === "selectarea:selected") {
                leafletEvent = {
                  type: event,
                  bounds: new LatLngBounds(
                    new LatLng(1, 1),
                    new LatLng(10, 10),
                  ),
                  start: new LatLng(1, 1),
                  end: new LatLng(10, 10),
                  sourceTarget: {},
                  target: {},
                };
              }
              events[event](leafletEvent);
            };

            document.addEventListener(event, handler);
            handlers[event] = handler;
          });

          // Cleanup function to remove event listeners
          return () => {
            Object.keys(handlers).forEach((event) => {
              document.removeEventListener(event, handlers[event]);
            });
          };
        }, [events]);

        return null;
      }),
    };
  });

